# Can I use <hgroup> with different <h> orders?

Tags: html

```
<hgroup>
    <h4>Employment</h4>
    <h3>Graphic designer</h3>
    <h5>Godigital</h5>
</hgroup>
```

Is this correct, or I should use order tags as `<h3><h4><h5>`?

Answer (score 3):

It's completely fine.

Only thing you have to remember is that you **can't put anything but `h1`-`h6` within `hgroup`**. Order doesn't matter.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is. More information [here](http://html5doctor.com/the-hgroup-element/).

> `<hgroup>` acts as a wrapper for one or more related heading
>   elements possibly contained within a  element. It can *only*
>   contain a group of `<h1>–<h6>` element(s), and it should be used for
>   subtitles, alternative titles, and tag lines.

Example:

```
<article>
  <hgroup>
    <h1>Title goes here</h1>
    <h2>Subtitle of article</h2>
  </hgroup>
  <p>Lorem Ipsum dolor set amet</p>
</article>
```

EDITED:
Following [this decision](http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/public-html-admin/2013Apr/0003.html), `hgroup` is removed from the HTML5 specification.

Answer (score 1):

It is difficult to infere something else from this context, but inside of a HTML file, this would be correct. You could use up to h6 tag.
[W3C hgroup](http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/hgroup)

Comment: w3schools is known to be inaccurate and misleading. See [w3fools](http://w3fools.com/).

Comment: Thx to all for the answer,  but then why the Validator says it is incorrect? "Nest headings properly (H1 > H2 > H3)"

<hgroup>
      <h2>
      + About me
      </h2>
      P883 [WCAG 2.0 1.3.1 (A)] Nest headings properly (H1 > H2 > H3):
      <h5>
      My name is John Doe, I am a multi diciplinar designer.
      </h5>
 </hgroup>